# Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, local-files

When trying to do a HTTP request using XMLHttpRequest from a local file, it basically fails due to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` violation.

However, I'm using the local web page myself, so I was wondering if there is any way to make Google Chrome allow these requests, which are from a local file to a URL on the Internet.

E.g., `$.get('http://www.google.com/')` fails when executing in a local file, but I've scripted the page myself and I'm using it myself, so it would be extremely useful if I could suppress it and load the URL.

So, how can I allow Google Chrome to load URLs using XMLHttpRequest from local files?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null` by the website works. (ofc. not by google.com)

Comment: @JessamynSmith: The order of answers changes, and the accepted answer may also change, so it's better to link to an answer than saying anything like 'the answer below the accepted answer'. Use the URL that the answer's 'share' link leads to.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Your comment is somewhat irrelevant given that I pasted in the actual command that worked. However, in case there is value in including the link, I deleted and resposted. In modern Chrome, errors look like: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/to/file/css/base.css. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4819114/1649165 worked for me, i.e. run chrome from the command line: chrome --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: @JessamynSmith: Sorry you thought my advice was irrelevant. Since you thought a particular answer was relevant, I thought you might like to future-proof your comment. My mistake.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

startup chrome with `--disable-web-security`

On Windows:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

On Mac:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security
```

This will allow for cross-domain requests.
I'm not aware of if this also works for local files, but let us know !

And mention, this does exactly what you expect, it **disables** the web security, so be careful with it.

Comment: You can also use Safari on a Mac. It allows AJAX to local files by default when the request is made from a local file. Also, about '.exe', nothing in the Q is said about Windows. Pim is a Windows dev, but still, nothing said about Windows.

Comment: Yes I'm on Windows, sorry about that. Will try this out now, thanks. By the way, I'm running Chrome always when my computer is on, so is there a way to only allow cross domain request with local files or only in a specific tab? Because this way, I actually cannot browse the Internet safely at the same time...

Comment: I just downloaded the latest Chromium build so as to have a standalone, unsafe version running for testing, and the 'real', installed Chrome for safe Internet browsing. And it does work, thanks!

Comment: @Tom - you should be able to do this on Mac with Safari, without any setting changes, as long as you use the "file:///" protocol and not "http://localhost"

Comment: Go with @Konstantin Smolyanin's suggestion

Comment: Better answer below to just allow file access.

Comment: I have done this and it works just fine. Please be aware that if you do this and then open a new chrome browser is it still running with web security disabled. You would need to kill all chrome instances and restart chrome to re-enable web security. 

@pimvdb 's solution works. I also have chrome canary and have used one for disabled security for testing. I just wante to mention this as it is easy to forget! Don't go online with web-security diasabled!

Comment: I tried it on Safari 10.1 and it gave me: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///<my_local_file>. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.` so the statement about Safari browser from this thread is no longer valid.

Comment: The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10673 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=3845, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}

Answer (score 266):

Using `--disable-web-security` switch is quite **dangerous**! Why disable security at all while you can just allow XMLHttpRequest to access files from other files using `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch?

Before using these commands be sure to end all running instances of Chrome.

On Windows:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

On Mac:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Discussions of this *"feature"* of Chrome:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37586,
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416,
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/v177zA6LCKU

Comment: Is it possible to make this the default behavior without having to open a terminal/command line or a custom shortcut every time?

Comment: @Kokodoko I think no.

Comment: Rather than disabling web security in the browser you could instead host the file making the cross-domain ajax request on a web server running on the local machine so that the scheme used does not have access to your filesystem. Reverse proxies are another way to handle this, and can be configured with relative ease using Node-based tools like Hapi or Express.

Comment: @JoshH I completely agree that it's much better to use local web server for web site development then accessing local files directly by the browser. However the exact question was asked and I've just answered it.

Comment: In case someone else is going to try this: this flag is *not* available/modifyable in `chrome://flags`

Comment: Is it safe to browse internet using this instance? In my case, when I opened the same local file in Iceweasel, there was no error. They don't have the same security check as Chrome does? So I'm guessing it's still okay to surf the web in this browser instance.

Comment: @BlackPanda I think it's safe because of [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Sites from internet still can't access local files.

Comment: On Windows it won't work if chrome is already running  and is sharing its instances.

Comment: Please note, you may have extensions to chrome that don't shutdown when you close chrome, leaving chrome running in the background. In this case changing the shortcut will appear to do nothing. I had to end task all the `chrome.exe` instances running to get this to work this time.

Comment: @Kokodoko You can consider downloading Chromium and using it ONLY for debugging. If you do in this way, you need launching the Chromium with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag only once - and it will be MORE CONVENIENT if you set Chromium as the default app for HTML file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @Kokodoko yes it is. You have to change the "launcher settings". Under Windows: Open start menu -> find chromium -> right click -> properties -> somewhere here you find the path to the executable file. Just add the command line parameter after the executable call.

Answer (score 22):

Mac version. From terminal run:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: it would be nice to have a more permanent solution. This one assumes the user knows in advance and also requires a relaunch of chrome.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any longer in current versions of Chrome.

Comment: FWIW it works for me with Chrome 106.0.5249.91 on macOS 12.6 (21G115)

Answer (score 3):

**On Ubuntu:**

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```

For more details/switches:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

[Referenced from](https://opensourcehacker.com/2010/11/29/disabling-cross-domain-security-check-for-ajax-development-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: I think specifying files will be safer 
`
google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files ~/foo

`

Comment: This is a bit broad for the specific use case. But props for a solution regardless