# jQuery $.get from local directory producing different behaviour in IE vs FF, Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple jQuery:

```
 $.get('Data.csv', function(data) {

    alert(data);

 });
```

`Data.csv` is stored in the same folder as the html file which accesses it.

If I run this in all browsers when the url is a domain (i.e. www.mysite.com/path/to/file), then the alert will display a string value of the contents of `Data.csv`.

If I create a hosts file link to the local folder (i.e. host.mysite.com/path/to/file) then alert will display a string value of the contents of `Data.csv` in all browsers.

If I run this in IE 9 when the url opens the file locally (i.e c:\path\to\file) then the alert will display a string value of the contents of `Data.csv`.

However, if I run this in FF or Chrome when the url opens the file locally (i.e file:///c:/path/to/file) then the alert will display `[object XMLDocument]`.

Does anyone know why this is and how to open the local file as a string in FF and Chrome?

n.b. - I have tested this in order to rule out cross-platform-security issues. I don't think that that is the cause because otherwise it would not assign the content of the csv file at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use Firebug and set a breakpoint at the alert(data), you  should be able to see the objects actual properties..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into issues with the Same Origin Policy. If you look into your browser's console, you'll see something along the lines of `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

There's two possible fixes:

1. Run your stuff on a local web server like XAMPP, MAMP or the like.
2. [Disable all web security on Chrome Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file/4819114#4819114), which you obviously don't want to do in real life. Wouldn't work in FF, either. So, stick with 1. ;)