# How to read local Json files in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Please note this application will never be running on a server system.

I am trying to read a local json file the code I am using is:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/Users/michael/jscrud/json/test.json')
  .done(function(data) {
 //do something here
}
```

I also need to be able to change this file adding meta data about the changes made.
Any help would be great thanks. As I have spent 3 days trying to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers prohibit file requests from JavaScript, but they also generally have non-standard way to disable it for local debugging purposes (see, for example, [solution for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)). However, absolutely no browser will allow you to change data, as it simply not how things regularly work online - you can't tell some server to "change file at this URL", so there's no support for such thing for file:// protocol either.

Comment: you can also use safari on a mac