# I can't get the following ajax call to run in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code isn't working in Chrome and I want to make sure it works in all browsers:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'homepage_marquee/marquee_panels.html',
    context: document.body,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('.marquee_panel_data').html(data);
        setUpMarquee();
    }
});
```

The ajax is supposed to cycle through some splash screens which is in the `marquee_panels.html` file.  It only displays the first panel on Chrome.  I don't get any errors.  Works fine in IE9 and Safari.

I have tried local file access and hosted via Apache.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work ? Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: What is the error reported by the chrome developer tools console?

Comment: Try using an absolute URL instead of a relative one (i.e change it to http://example.com/homepage_marquee/marquee_panels.html). Also note the domain name (example.com) for the ajax call must be the same as the page you have open.

Comment: I think you might be running into issues with Chrome and local file access, similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file When I try running a local `html` and have a local `.js` referenced which does for example a jQuery `.load()` to another local `.html` I get local file access issues but only in Chrome but not in IE9 or latest FF.

Comment: I tried adding the complete url (example.com and www.example.com prefix) did not do anything different. I also tried disabling the chrome web security but no luck.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: No the OP should NOT create a new question on the exact same subject.  He already has a question here and needed to expand on it.  This will get reopened when it's valid.  Creating a new question now will most certainly result in that one getting closed too, which won't look good.

Comment: @CeylonSoft:  Can you modify your post to add the code for the `setUpMarquee()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a leading slash to the url.

```
url: '/homepage_marquee/marquee_panels.html',
```

this is a correct relative path.

Comment: The leading slash did not work. The ajax is suppose to cycle through some splash screens which is in the marquee_panels.html. It only displays the first panel on Chrome. I don't get any errors. It works fine in IE9 and Safari.