# Having problems with d3.json, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm fairly new to both Javascript and D3, and I've been trying to try the examples from the website myself.

I used the following for the JS/HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

    <head>
    <body>
        <script>
        d3.json("mydata.json", function (data) { 
            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500)

            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 10; })
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 50; })
                .attr("fill", "blue")
        })
           </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and for my "mydata.json" I am using:

```
[
    {"name": "Maria",   "age": 30},
    {"name": "Fred",    "age": 50},
    {"name": "Jason",   "age": 12}  
]
```

Every-time I try and run it, it doesn't have the same result as the examples on the d3 examples page. Please help, I am try to figure out how d3 works, and I am quite a novice programmer.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't have the same result? Note that you cannot load local files using `d3.json`, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work).

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting, but your code sets the `width` attribute of the `<rect>` elements but not the `height`; similarly, it sets the `y` position but not the `x` position. Without those properties, the results won't be very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to set the `height` attribute to display something.

A good way of debugging this kind of problem is to first make everything work without the json call. To do so I would recommend you to use the chrome javascript console to display errors and the chrome inspector to see the html code.

```
data = [{
    "name": "Maria",
    "age": 30
}, {
    "name": "Fred",
    "age": 50
}, {
    "name": "Jason",
    "age": 12
}]
//d3.json("mydata.json", function (data) { 
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)

canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return d.age * 10;
    })
    .attr("height", "20px")        
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
    .attr("fill", "blue")
//})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/LX9BF/

Answer (score 1):

As [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/372333/41621), the problem stems from a security restriction when using `file://` style URLs.

One solution, other than embedding the JSON object in your `.js` file, is to load the files via http. This is easily achieved using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)!

Follow these steps:

1. [Install nodejs](http://nodejs.org/download/).
2. Open a command prompt, then `cd` to your demo folder.
3. Type the command: **`npm install Express`**. This will install the Express web-server components into the `.\node_modules` folder.
4. Create a new web-server.js file with the contents shown below.
5. Invoke the server by typing `node .\web-server.js` on the command-line.
6. Create a sub-folder called *`htdocs`* then move your `.html`, `.js`, and `.json` files, and any other *web assets* into it. This will be the *root folder* of your web site.
7. Open a browser and navigate to `http://localhost:9999/[your-html-file].html`, where [your-html-file] is replaced with the actual filename.

**web-server.js**

```
var server_port = 9999;
var application_root = __dirname + "\\htdocs",
    express = require("express"),
    path = require("path");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(application_root));
app.use(app.router);
app.listen(server_port);
console.log("Web server listening on port " + server_port + ".");
```

This should get you past the issue of loading the `.json` file. In fact, it's useful whenever you need a light-weight web server to test code with.