# using geoJson to draw a map with d3.js

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, geojson

I am trying to create a Map of any country from geoJson file using d3.js

Below is the code of html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <title>Demo d3</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="file://d:AUS.jsonp"></script>
    </head>

<body>

<script>

var canvass=d3.select("body").append("svg")
                             .attr("width",900)
                             .attr("height",900);

d3.json("AUS.json",function(data){

var group=canvass.selectAll("g")
                 .data(data.features).
                 .enter()
                 .append("g")

var projection=d3.geo.mercator().scale(7300).translate([]0,1980);
var path=d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

var areas=group.append("path")
               .attr("d",path)
                .attr("class","area")
                .attr("fill","blue");



});

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have kept the AUS.json file locally in the same path as that of HTML file but when I open the HTML page I don't get any map.

I think that HTML file is not able to open that JSON file.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: It looks like you have a typo -- should be `.translate([0,1980]);`.

Comment: sry ,yes it was a typo error.but changing it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error message? You may have run into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work).

Comment: No error message.There is a similar post check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work. but the solution is not clear.

Comment: If you're not getting an error message then that's probably not the problem. It may simply be the case that the map is zoomed/translated to a position where you can't see anything. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) may help with that.

Comment: If I debug in chrome and check the body of html page,I don't see any tag created by d3 which means that page is not generating map.

Comment: Not even the `svg` tag?

Comment: I believe that this code d3.json("AUS.json",function(data){  makes an http request to get that file.But the file is in local folder so it fails.In the browser console I am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load AUS.json"

Comment: SVG is getting generated after solving last typo error..

Comment: Right, so you do have the same problem as in the question I've linked to. Have you tried any of those answers?

Comment: No My script is not able to access the local json file ie. I get message in the console "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/xyx/Desktop/New%20folder/AUS.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP"

Comment: Yes -- have you tried including the JSON in your HTML file?

Comment: Sorry to say that .But could you tell me how..I think even if i add json into html page,how will the call to d3.json("AUS.json",function(data)  will access JSON included in HTML?As d3.json makes an HTTP call

Comment: Put `data = <contents of JSON file>;` instead of the call to `d3.json`.

Comment: I am not sure how the binding will happen then..Sorry to bother a lot

Comment: Remove the call to `d3.json`, keeping only what's inside the callback function. Then copy and paste the contents of the JSON file as outlined above.

Comment: Okay..Now path is generated under svg tag..but it is still not visible..

Comment: Hey its working..thanks a lot..yipee.I don't believe you had lot of patience..thanks again..

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer for reference please?