# python on Windows : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 3: invalid start byte

Tags: javascript, python, json, windows, d3.js

`Python 3.6.4`
`Windows10`

I am trying to load a `json` file from url
However, when I try
`d3.json("http://ip_addr/field/parameters", function(error, data) {
       console.log(data)
}`

I have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

I tried a solution
[click here to see more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26030944/8251353)
But when I typed

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>python -m http.server 8888 &`

I have error message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\server.py", line 1211, in <module>
    test(HandlerClass=handler_class, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\server.py", line 1185, in test
    with ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass) as httpd:
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\xieda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 3: invalid start byte`

How can I fix the problem? Or is there any solutions to my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error?

Comment: @what is your code

Comment: @MukulSharma   I have given my code. What code do you need

Comment: My hosts file doesn't contain any non-ascii characters.@snakecharmerb