# File structure of d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am very very new to D3 and wanted to make something very similar to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/zross/6a31f4ef9e778d94c204)

I have created a file called index.html with all the same code as is given on the web page.

I also have another file called points.geojson in the same directory...again with all the same data given.

When opening index.html the path is not generated... is the points.geojson file meant to be in the same place?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work

Comment: Post a fiddle/plunkr if you are still stuck.