# Not seeing d3 svg on server, but works with local file

Tags: d3.js, svg

If I load a local D3/js file in my browser like this:
`file://users/mmaxson/dumps/test.html`
the D3 bar plots render in SVG elements.

But if I move that to my server, here:
`http://storylearning.org/s/mchanga/analysis.html`
The D3 elements don't appear. The SVG elements are there, but they aren't rendering graphics.

It seems to be putting all the charts on top of each other. 
I'm pasting the code below:
(I copied this recipe from http://bl.ocks.org/Jverma/887877fc5c2c2d99be10)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<style>
.bar{
fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover{
fill: brown;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

<script>
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);
// add the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.json('', function() {
// mydata 
//var myjson = '[{"Letter":"A","Freq":20},{"Letter":"B","Freq":12},{"Letter":"C","Freq":47},{"Letter":"D","Freq":34},{"Letter":"E","Freq":54},{"Letter":"F","Freq":21},{"Letter":"G","Freq":57},{"Letter":"H","Freq":31},{"Letter":"I","Freq":17},{"Letter":"J","Freq":5},{"Letter":"K","Freq":23},{"Letter":"L","Freq":39},{"Letter":"M","Freq":29},{"Letter":"N","Freq":33},{"Letter":"O","Freq":18},{"Letter":"P","Freq":35},{"Letter":"Q","Freq":11},{"Letter":"R","Freq":45},{"Letter":"S","Freq":43},{"Letter":"T","Freq":28},{"Letter":"U","Freq":26},{"Letter":"V","Freq":30},{"Letter":"X","Freq":5},{"Letter":"Y","Freq":4},{"Letter":"Z","Freq":2}]'
var myjson = '[{"Freq": 3072, "Letter": "6000"}, {"Freq": 540, "Letter": "12192"}, {"Freq": 315, "Letter": "14227"}, {"Freq": 308, "Letter": "10164"}, {"Freq": 257, "Letter": "4620"}, {"Freq": 240, "Letter": "3353"}, {"Freq": 87, "Letter": "754"}, {"Freq": 33, "Letter": "5861"}, {"Freq": 10, "Letter": "11600"}, {"Freq": 5, "Letter": "5204"}, {"Freq": 1, "Letter": "11781"}, {"Freq": 1, "Letter": "904"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "5781"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "16943"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "8065"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "18309"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "2351"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "16583"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "7493"}, {"Freq": 0, "Letter": "8018"}]' // be sure to replace any single quotes here. send in real JSON with double quotes.
// load the data
data = JSON.parse( myjson );
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Letter = d.Letter;
    d.Freq = +d.Freq;
});

// scale the range of the data
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Freq; })]);
// add axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 5)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");
// Add bar chart
svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Freq); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Freq); });
});

</script>
mchanga local giving challenge 2016

 <hr><br> 

<style>
.bar{
fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover{
fill: brown;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

<script>
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);
// add the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.json('', function() {
// mydata 
//var myjson = '[{"Letter":"A","Freq":20},{"Letter":"B","Freq":12},{"Letter":"C","Freq":47},{"Letter":"D","Freq":34},{"Letter":"E","Freq":54},{"Letter":"F","Freq":21},{"Letter":"G","Freq":57},{"Letter":"H","Freq":31},{"Letter":"I","Freq":17},{"Letter":"J","Freq":5},{"Letter":"K","Freq":23},{"Letter":"L","Freq":39},{"Letter":"M","Freq":29},{"Letter":"N","Freq":33},{"Letter":"O","Freq":18},{"Letter":"P","Freq":35},{"Letter":"Q","Freq":11},{"Letter":"R","Freq":45},{"Letter":"S","Freq":43},{"Letter":"T","Freq":28},{"Letter":"U","Freq":26},{"Letter":"V","Freq":30},{"Letter":"X","Freq":5},{"Letter":"Y","Freq":4},{"Letter":"Z","Freq":2}]'
var myjson = '[{"Freq": "37380", "Letter": "24891"}, {"Freq": "26145.18", "Letter": "24863"}, {"Freq": "20171", "Letter": "25257"}, {"Freq": "12971", "Letter": "25557"}, {"Freq": "9190", "Letter": "24795"}, {"Freq": "8918", "Letter": "24613"}, {"Freq": "7430", "Letter": "24759"}, {"Freq": "7310", "Letter": "25244"}, {"Freq": "7085", "Letter": "24487"}, {"Freq": "7057", "Letter": "24582"}, {"Freq": "6810", "Letter": "17371"}, {"Freq": "6595", "Letter": "25198"}, {"Freq": "6560", "Letter": "24933"}, {"Freq": "6535", "Letter": "18503"}, {"Freq": "6413", "Letter": "22358"}, {"Freq": "6252.98", "Letter": "24926"}, {"Freq": "6120", "Letter": "25104"}, {"Freq": "6080", "Letter": "25241"}, {"Freq": "6078", "Letter": "24385"}, {"Freq": "5990", "Letter": "24668"}]' // be sure to replace any single quotes here. send in real JSON with double quotes.
// load the data
data = JSON.parse( myjson );
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Letter = d.Letter;
    d.Freq = +d.Freq;
});

// scale the range of the data
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Freq; })]);
// add axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 5)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");
// Add bar chart
svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Freq); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Freq); });
});

</script>
September 2014 Global Open Challenge

<br><br>

<style>
.bar{
fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover{
fill: brown;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

<script>
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);
// add the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.json('', function() {
// mydata 
//var myjson = '[{"Letter":"A","Freq":20},{"Letter":"B","Freq":12},{"Letter":"C","Freq":47},{"Letter":"D","Freq":34},{"Letter":"E","Freq":54},{"Letter":"F","Freq":21},{"Letter":"G","Freq":57},{"Letter":"H","Freq":31},{"Letter":"I","Freq":17},{"Letter":"J","Freq":5},{"Letter":"K","Freq":23},{"Letter":"L","Freq":39},{"Letter":"M","Freq":29},{"Letter":"N","Freq":33},{"Letter":"O","Freq":18},{"Letter":"P","Freq":35},{"Letter":"Q","Freq":11},{"Letter":"R","Freq":45},{"Letter":"S","Freq":43},{"Letter":"T","Freq":28},{"Letter":"U","Freq":26},{"Letter":"V","Freq":30},{"Letter":"X","Freq":5},{"Letter":"Y","Freq":4},{"Letter":"Z","Freq":2}]'
var myjson = '[{"Freq": "28455", "Letter": "26970"}, {"Freq": "16289", "Letter": "26192"}, {"Freq": "15510", "Letter": "7323"}, {"Freq": "15375", "Letter": "26569"}, {"Freq": "12979", "Letter": "26693"}, {"Freq": "10185", "Letter": "26160"}, {"Freq": "9809", "Letter": "25313"}, {"Freq": "9108", "Letter": "26466"}, {"Freq": "9091", "Letter": "25253"}, {"Freq": "8758", "Letter": "3479"}, {"Freq": "7022", "Letter": "26735"}, {"Freq": "6765", "Letter": "26684"}, {"Freq": "6700", "Letter": "26717"}, {"Freq": "6482", "Letter": "26761"}, {"Freq": "6465", "Letter": "12399"}, {"Freq": "6407", "Letter": "15012"}, {"Freq": "6151", "Letter": "25850"}, {"Freq": "6147", "Letter": "25633"}, {"Freq": "6143", "Letter": "24388"}, {"Freq": "6078", "Letter": "25082"}]' // be sure to replace any single quotes here. send in real JSON with double quotes.
// load the data
data = JSON.parse( myjson );
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Letter = d.Letter;
    d.Freq = +d.Freq;
});

// scale the range of the data
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Freq; })]);
// add axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 5)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");
// Add bar chart
svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Freq); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Freq); });
});

</script>
December 2014 Global Open Challenge
```

Comment: Maybe this line matters: `d3.json('', function() {`? This may behave differently on local vs hosted page.
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work

Comment: Yeah, I was specifically trying to convert code that loads a local CSV file into D3 into one that would parse a JSON. What's the write syntax there?