# D3.js - Can't read json file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a d3.js project and I'm struggling with reading in my json file (my data doesn't load). I'm not sure if it's an issue with my code or my file.

My location.json file looks like this (first few lines)

```
[
{
"Latitude": 15.64624,
"Longitude": 32.46113,
"": ""
},
{
"Latitude": 37.67971,
"Longitude": -121.9076,
"": ""
},
{
"Latitude": 40.51361,
"Longitude": -74.25005999999998,
"": ""
}
]
```

My source code looks like this:

```
d3.json('../static/data/serial_killers/location.json', function(error, 
mapData) {
var features = mapData.features;

   map.selectAll('.geo-path') 
  .data(features)
  .enter().append('path')
  .attr('class', 'geo-path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .attr("visibility", "visible")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.5);
  });
```

I also tried to tackle it this way, to no prevail

```
d3.json("../static/data/serial_killers/location.json", 
function(topology) {
map.selectAll('.geo-path')
.data(topology.features)
.enter()
.append('path')
.attr('class', 'geo-path')
.attr('d', path)
.attr("visibility", "visible")
.style("stroke-opacity", 1)
.style("fill-opacity", 0.5);
 });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's not valid JSON. There's a trailing comma at the end, and no closing square bracket. How is the JSON file created? Are you composing it manually? Don't. PHP for instance has `json_encode()`.

Comment: @ChrisG sorry about that - the json i posted here was just a slice of a much longer file (no trailing comma, and the square bracket is included - i edited it in the code above). That being said, do you know what else may be wrong?

Comment: According to the docs, the `.json` command seems to return a promise and is to be used like: `d3.json(url).then(function (mapData) {  ...  });`

Comment: If your running that outside of a webserver, ie from a file directory, its probably not going to work for security reasons.  How are you running it?

Comment: @terpinmd i have the file saved in one of my folders on my laptop (so i guess locally) ... i didnt think this would be an issue..?

Comment: See if this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work