# jqGrid data not loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid, asp.net-web-api

im working on an MVC project that also includes a WEB API project. Basically im making a call from my MVC project to the API project to query data that will appear in a jqGrid. However, I cannot get any data to load in the grid, it just says "loading" and then nothing happens. Here how I have everything setup:

My controller on the Web API side:

```
static readonly IWellRepository repository = new WellRepository();

    WellsMigrationEntities db = new WellsMigrationEntities();

    // GET api/values
   public dynamic Get(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
      var wells = repository.GetAll() as IEnumerable<vwWell>;
      var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
      var pageSize = rows;
      var totalRecords = wells.Count();
      var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
      wells = wells.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
      return new
      {
          total = totalPages,
          page = page,
          records = totalRecords,
          rows = (
              from well in wells
              select new
              {
                  //i = well.APINumber,
                  cell = new string[] {
                     well.APINumber,
                     well.CountyName,
                     well.LeaseName,
                     well.WellNumber 
                  }
              }).ToArray()
      };
    }
```

My repository method that gets called within the Controller:

```
WellsMigrationEntities db = new WellsMigrationEntities();

    public IEnumerable<vwWell> GetAll()
    {
        return db.vwWells.Where(o => o.CountyName == "Butte").ToList();
    }
```

and Finally here is my JqGrid thats being loaded in my MVC project:

```
<script>
var API_URL = "http://localhost:41389/api/well";
jQuery("#gridMain").jqGrid({
    url: API_URL,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    pager: '#pagernav',
    sortable: true,
    height: 200,
    viewrecords: true,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        page: function () { return 1; },
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },
    colNames: ['APINumber', 'CountyName', 'LeaseName', 'WellNumber'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'APINumber', index: 'APINumber', width: 40, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
     { name: 'CountyName', index: 'CountyName', editable: true, edittype: 'text', width: 70 },
     { name: 'LeaseName', index: 'LeaseName', editable: true, edittype: 'text', width: 70 },
     { name: 'WellNumber', index: 'WellNumber', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
    ],
    caption: "jqGrid",
    autowidth: true

});
```

No matter what i try, data will not load! Heres what the output is from my Get moethod in my controller:

```
{{"$id":"1","total":13,"page":1,"records":260,"rows":[{"$id":"2","cell":["00700001","Butte","Parrott Inv. Co.","9A-3"]},{"$id":"3","cell":["00700002","Butte","Wild Goose Gas Unit 1","9"]},{"$id":"4","cell":["00700003","Butte","Wild Goose Gas Unit 1","10"]},{"$id":"5","cell":["00700004","Butte","Wild Goose Gas Unit 1","6"]},{"$id":"6","cell":["00700005","Butte","Capital Co.","1"]},{"$id":"7","cell":["00700006","Butte","Estes","1"]},{"$id":"8","cell":["00700007","Butte","Capital Co.","E-1"]},{"$id":"9","cell":["00700008","Butte","Donohoe Fee","1"]},{"$id":"10","cell":["00700009","Butte","Donohoe Fee","2"]},{"$id":"11","cell":["00700010","Butte","T. W. Rodgers","1"]},{"$id":"12","cell":["00700011","Butte","Wahl Community","1"]},{"$id":"13","cell":["00700012","Butte","Towne","1"]},{"$id":"14","cell":["00700013","Butte","Wild Goose Gas Unit 1","1"]},{"$id":"15","cell":["00700014","Butte","Neaves-Parrott Inv.","2"]},{"$id":"16","cell":["00700015","Butte","Neaves-Parrott Inv.","7"]},{"$id":"17","cell":["00700016","Butte","Parrott Inv. Co.","1"]},{"$id":"18","cell":["00700018","Butte","Parrott Investment Co.","1"]},{"$id":"19","cell":["00700019","Butte","Urich Oil -Parrott","2"]},{"$id":"20","cell":["00700020","Butte","Parrott Investment Co.","2"]},{"$id":"21","cell":["00700021","Butte","Parrott Investment Co.","3"]}]}}
```

Why is the data not loading for me?

UPDATE:

by the way, this is the url that is being sent to my controller from jqGrid

```
http://localhost:41389/api/well?_search=false&nd=1384556871623&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. After debugging in IE, I found one issue. The button control was not enclosed in quotes $("#btnContactList").click(function (){} Even after correcting, I am still facing an issue. The data would not load in jqGrid. I wonder if it is a reliable control looking at such issues.
Here's my question posted. See if you guys can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131283/jqgrid-not-rendering-data-headers-visible **I have solved the issue. Please see my post for details. It was the jsonReader attribute that was missing and was causing the problem. Problem solved.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the data structure that you're returning for the rows. When you're returning cell, you're not passing any "key" information that your grid can parse for the columns. Therefore, just return an array of the `vwWell` objects

```
 // GET api/values


public dynamic Get(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
      var wells = repository.GetAll() as IEnumerable<vwWell>;
      var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
      var pageSize = rows;
      var totalRecords = wells.Count();
      var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
      wells = wells.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
      var jsonData = new
      {
          total = totalPages,
          page = page,
          records = totalRecords,
          rows = wells.ToArray() //We need an array of objects for the rows
      };
      return jsonData;
    }
```

*Note* You'll need to include System.Web.Mvc namespace if it's not included

Comment: Can you even return a Json object using Web API project? Says Json does not exist in this current context, and ive added the MVC namespace.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that you were using Web API. I'm not sure. If so, the return type should be ActionResult

Comment: Yeah Im using the web API side to store all my models and database connections. on my MVC side all im doing is displaying the grid. Is there something wrong with my Json format?

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the way your "cell" structure is populated. You need key/value pairs in there. I'll update the answer for you to try.

Comment: Thanks for the update, didnt work though, but I see what you are saying about there not being any key data. One problem I see now is there is no "cell data in the format. It now reads {"$id":"1","total":13,"page":1,"records":260,"rows":[{"$id":"2","APINumber":"00700001","CountyName":"Butte","LeaseName":"Parrott Inv. Co.", etc..................Should there be something signifying the start of a row? Btw now the JSON data that gets retrieves is ALL the database data, not just the specified ones I had before. Thanks for you help btw I need it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out and I feel stupid.

Apparently debugging in Chrome does not work well. Changed deployment to IE, and it works just fine now -_-

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the grid. I'm not sure how your API fetches data, but it sounds like you might be running into a cross-domain request issue. Chrome doesn't allow cross-domain requests by default, but IE does. To disable in Chrome, see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file