# jqGrid not rendering data - Headers visible

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

While playing around with jqGrid, I ran into the following issue. The data in jqGrid is not getting rendered. Even though I am able to see the header of the grid with all the columns but the data does not appear. I am returning the data from an action method of the controller in a JSON format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("this is a test");
            $(btnContactList).click(function () {
                $("#ContactTable").jqGrid({
                    url: "/Contact/ContactList",
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name", "EMail"],
                    colModel: [
                        //{ name: "ContactId", index: "ContactId", width: 80 },
                        { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 100 },
                        { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 100 },
                        { name: "EMail", index: "EMail", width: 200 }
                    ],
                    //data: result,
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    //loadonce: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    caption: "List Contact Details",
                    emptyrecords: "No records to display",
                    jsonReader: {
                        root: "rows",
                        page: "page",
                        id: 0

                    }
                });
                alert("complete - success");
           });

        });


 </script>
```

Action method in the controller:

```
public JsonResult ContactList()
    {
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

        contacts.Add ( new Contact()
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Email = "john.doe@gmail.com"
            }
        );



        return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Network tab output showing the JSON data returned by the call to Action method 'ContactList' as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

The jqGrid header is also being rendered but the data (in JSON format) returned by Controller's Action method is not getting rendered into the jqGrid.

[image]

Where am I making a mistake here?

Even after modifying the code as advised by @Oleg in his comment below, the problem persists. There was no error. The alert from 'loadComplete' event popped up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("this is a test");
            $(btnContactList).click(function () {



                $("#ContactTable").jqGrid({
                    url: "/Contact/ContactList",
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name", "EMail"],
                    colModel: [

                        { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 100 },
                        { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 100 },
                        { name: "EMail", index: "EMail", width: 200 }
                    ],
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    loadonce: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    caption: "List Contact Details",
                    emptyrecords: "No records to display",
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        alert("Complete ok!")
                    },
                    loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                            'textstatus: ' + textstatus + '\n' +
                            'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                        alert('HTTP message body  (jqXHR.responseText: ' +     '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                });
                alert("complete - success");

            });

        });
```

Comment: **which version of jqGrid you use?** I recommend you to add `loadonce: true` option and `loadError` callback (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)). The `jsonReader` which you use contains wrong information. You can remove it if you use not so old version of jqGrid or add `jsonReader: { root: function (obj) { return obj; } }`.

Comment: This is what I found at the top of the file "jquery.jqGrid.min.js" -              jqGrid  4.4.3 - jQuery Grid

Comment: After running into such issues, I wonder how reliable this grid control is. I can see the response in JSON format, despite that the grid cannot bind it with the data.

Comment: When I click the button for the first time, the data is now successfully loaded into the grid. However, if I re-click the button nothing happens. I expected it to re-load the grid and reload the data also but it does not work that way. Wonder why it behaves this way?

Comment: It's clear, because `$("#ContactTable").jqGrid({...});` **create the grid**. It means that it convert initial empty table into relatively complex structure of dives and tables. You can either create the grid once and the call `$("#ContactTable").trigger("reloadGrid");` later to reload *the body* of the grid or you can add alternatively `$("#ContactTable").jqGrid("GridUnload");` **before** creating the grid. It will destroy jqGrid if any exist. More problem in your code is the usage of no pager. I recommend you to add at least top pager `toppager: true` or to add `rowNum: 1000` (20 is default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked. Thank you @Oleg! I saw another post here http://goo.gl/Pg5CMn

Additionally, I figured that I was making another mistake. I forgot to enclose btnContactList in double quotes. After debugging in Internet explorer, I found that out. Secondly, as @Oleg suggested that the jsonReader attribute is required. Probably because of the version of jqGrid that I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("this is a test");
            $("#btnContactList").click(function () {

                $("#ContactTable").jqGrid({
                    url: "/Contact/ContactList",
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ["ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "EMail"],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: "ContactId", index: "ContactId", width: 80 },
                        { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 100 },
                        { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 100 },
                        { name: "EMail", index: "EMail", width: 200 }
                    ],
                    //data: result,
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    loadonce: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    caption: "List Contact Details",
                    emptyrecords: "No records to display",
                    jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false,
                        //page: function () { return 1; },
                        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                        //records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                    },
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        alert("Complete ok!")
                    },
                    loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                            'textstatus: ' + textstatus + '\n' +
                            'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                        alert('HTTP message body  (jqXHR.responseText: ' +     '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }

                });
                alert("after completion");

            });


        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You use **very old version**. It has no auto-detection of input format. So you have to specify `jsonReader` which exact corresponds your data. At least two properties of `jsonReader` are really required:

```js
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj; } 
}
```

The above settings should fix the main problem. Additionally one should understand that jqGrid assign `id` attribute to every row (every `<tr>` element). If you would implement later other features of jqGrid (editing for example) you will need to identify the rows by id. So it's strictly recommended to include `id` property in the input data. If you have native id of the `Contact` object with another name (`"Id"` or `"ContactId"` for example) you can specify the additional `id` property inside of `jsonReader` (as `id: "Id"` or `id: "ContactId"`). You should include the corresponding property in the server response too.

I would recommend you to consider to update jqGrid to the latest [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (or at least to [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/tree/v4.8.0)). You can read more about the features of free jqGrid in [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/README.md) and in [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid which I develop.

Comment: It finally worked! Before I saw your response, I tried the same thing and it worked but thank you so much for the help! You nailed it.

Comment: Will consider upgrading the version. Thanks again for your help!