# Unable to plot waveform of audiofile using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, cordova, waveform

Here is the scenario:

- I am recording an audio file using cordova's media plugin and saving the recorded file as *myRecordingPath* in the documents directory of the app. The fileSystem has following path:

  ```
  */var/mobile/Applications/B2EA8890-E5AA-4273-83C4-EB4CA045EA/Documents/
  2192014125156.wav*
  ```
- Now I am loading the same recorded file in a different view to play the recording using Cordova's media plugin (again). It plays fine.
- I also wanted to display the waveform of the same file so I am using *[Chris Wilson's](https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Buffer-Draw)* audio-buffer-draw library. I have tested out the same in chrome but in my application, its not working.
- I am trying to pass the recorded file as follows:

  ```
  var audioSource = 'file://'+myRecordingPath;

  function initAudio() {

      var audioRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      audioSource.crossOrigin='anonymous';
      audioRequest.open("GET", audioSource, true);
      audioRequest.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      audioRequest.onload = function() {
      audioContext.decodeAudioData( audioRequest.response,
                               function(buffer) {
                               var canvas = document.getElementById("wave");
                               drawBuffer( canvas.width, canvas.height, canvas.getContext('2d'), buffer );
                               } );
                            }
                 audioRequest.send();
           }
  ```

The audio is playing fine but the waveform is not being loaded in the canvas.

Is there something to do with relative path?

I have even used [WaveSurfer.js](http://wavesurfer.fm/) and [Shore.js](https://github.com/Codingbean/Shore) but both of them are using similar concept and yielding same results. Result is: Waveform is not being created.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

I expect your problem is that XMLHTTPRequest doesn't by default work for local files: [Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file).  Cross-origin controls don't apply to non-HTTP requests.

Comment: I am doing this in a mobile app using PhoneGap. How would I achieve the same ?

Comment: I think you need http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide.

Comment: Thanks @cwilso but its already <access origin="*" /> by default