# Angular Partials: templateUrl Routing Local .HTML File

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, url-routing, partials

I've had this problem for over 2 days and I've spent around 10 hours researching, but NOTHING has worked so far. I'm keeping my stress levels in check, but this is downright infuriating!

This jsfiddle has everything aside from the "page1.html" file that I'm trying to load

http://jsfiddle.net/tAmr3/

---

I want to load a sibling (same directory), page1.html file as such:

```
var playground = angular.module("playground",['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/Page1', {
      templateUrl: 'page1.html', // **THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK**
      controller:'page1Ctrl'
    }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'})
  });
```

---

The problem is that "templateUrl" refuses to work!!!

The `$routeProvider` knows when I'm trying to access `Page1` because `page1Ctrl` is console.logging successfully

Comment: Your fiddle is using inline templates with `<script type="text/ng-template"` so there is no HTML request for the template. So why do you believe CORS is the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: Your fiddle is also wrong btw, you're using `template` instead of `templateUrl` for the `$routeProvider`

Comment: Yes, I purposely changed it for the fiddle, so you can see the desired effect. If I leave that <script> tag out, I will get a CORS error in the console, and I read somewhere to include it as such

Comment: In the fiddle, there is no page1.html

Comment: Are you opening your application from the file system or serving it from a webserver?

Comment: Not using a webserver, just plain old HTML with script inclusion

Comment: If the resulting request is a HTTP request and the app was opened from a file, then that will result in a cross-origin request because the protocols are different

Comment: I guess I don't understand how I'm making an HTTP request

Comment: Is there a way to use the file from the same directory, without using HTTP request?

Comment: I've never actually worked with an angular app served over `file://` but it seems from looking at similar questions on this site that it's not very practical. Similar issue with some answers here if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536450/cant-open-angular-app-using-file-protocol-in-chrome

Comment: If your usecase allows it, I would suggest setting up a webserver though.

Comment: Is there any way to set up a simple server without using batch installs? -- EDIT I see the python method, I'm going to try that I guess..

Comment: Tried the SimpleHTTPServer, still templateUrl loads nothing

Comment: Is it a 404 error now instead of a CORS error?

Comment: OMG, it works, I just had to take out the script ng-template tag!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was serving the angular app over `file://` and having Angular trigger a cross-origin request when it tried to fetch the template over `http://`.

The easiest solution to that is to use a webserver rather than accessing the file-system directly.