# AngularJS views rendering issue - blank page

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have small problem, my AngularJS app doesn't work properly.
Everything seems to be fine... but when I open project's page, it's blank...
AngularJS works properly on this page, cause I've checked simple examples, which appears and the page.
I tried a lot of solutions: adding id to html tag, adding ['ngRoute'] to the module, but it still doesn't work...

Here is code:
**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp" id="demoApp">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!-- placeholder for views -->
      <div ng-view="demoApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
      </div>
    </div>
    </script>
    <script>
      var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ['ngRoute']);

      demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("#/view1", {
            controller: "SiteController",
            templateUrl: "view1.html"
          });
        $routeProvider.when("#/view2", {
            controller: "SiteController",
            templateUrl: "view2.html"
          });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/view1.html" });
      });

      demoApp.controller("SiteController", function($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
          { name: 'Piotrek', city: 'Radom' },
          { name: 'Jan', city: 'Cracow' }
        ];

        $scope.addCustomer = function() {
          $scope.customers.push(
            {
              name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
              city: $scope.newCustomer.city
             });
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**view1.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>View 1</h2>
  Name:
  <br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
  <br />
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name">
      {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br />
  Customer Name:<br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
  <br />
  Customer City:<br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
  <br />
  <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
  <br />
  <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

**view2.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>View 2</h2>
  City:
  <br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="city" />
  <br />
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city">
      {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration of the `$routeProvider` looks suspect to me.

```
  demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("#/view1", {
        controller: "SiteController",
        templateUrl: "view1.html"
      });
    $routeProvider.when("#/view2", {
        controller: "SiteController",
        templateUrl: "view2.html"
      });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/view1.html" });
  });
```

I am pretty sure you need to omit the # from the `when` blocks and that you're supposed to refer to a path and not a template in the `otherwise`.

Try:

```
  demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/view1", {
        controller: "SiteController",
        templateUrl: "view1.html"
      });
    $routeProvider.when("/view2", {
        controller: "SiteController",
        templateUrl: "view2.html"
      });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/view1" });
  });
```

Comment: I changed config to the code, which you posted, but It still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, you're opening the app via a file?

Comment: Yes - I'm clicking twice on the test.html (as on normal icon/program).
Should it be open in a different way?

Comment: Yes, since Angular uses a lot of asynchronous requests for fetching data, it will be stopped by the built-in security settings in most browsers. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536450/cant-open-angular-app-using-file-protocol-in-chrome/23536690#23536690

Comment: Great - it's working now! Thank you! For all who has similar problems:
from terminal type: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080,then: http://localhost:8080/