# Getting a remote CSV file and putting it into a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript script, and I want to use a CSV file present in a remote url (for instance `https://not-my-domain.com/test.csv`) in it.

I don't need to parse the CSV, just to get it as a simple string. I've tried:

```
    function getCSV() {
        var file = "https://not-my-domain.com/test.csv";
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var allText;

        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    allText = rawFile.responseText;
        };

        rawFile.send();
        alert(allText); //UNDEFINED!
        return allText;
   }
```

But somehow the allText is still `undefined` after the function has terminated. If you could assist me in this little issue I'd be glad.

Comment: You're trying to alert the contents before the file has finished loading.

Comment: Ok, I suspected so. How can I block the program until it's done loading?

Comment: Consider putting `alert` (or doing any other necessary processing) inside `onreadystatechange`, otherwise it can fire before the Ajax request completes.

Comment: Cool, thanks. But obviously I want to do more complex stuff in this function. If I understand correctly, AJAX is async. So can I do some sort of callback function that will block the operation of the script?

Comment: If file you want to get is on server with different domain then it will not work. Read about Same Origin Policy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

use a lambda for an easy callback. You'll need a proxy to  fetch the remote domain csv, or be sure it has cors enabled.

```
function getCSV(func) {
        var file = "https://not-my-domain.com/test.csv";
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var allText;

        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    if(func!=undefined && typeof(func) == "function"){
                        func(allText);
                     }
        };

        rawFile.send();


}


getCSV(function(contents){
  alert(contents);
})
```

Comment: OK,  it seems more logical to me, thanks. But now it shows empty alert window, probably because of the same-origin policy. I want to mention that this script is client-side, so how that corresponds with the policy?

Comment: local host behavior depends on the browser.

Comment: Right. So what is the a universal way to just load a file into a string?

Comment: It's more complex than that. It depends on if the file is remote on a server, or the file is local on your machine. If everything is local on your machine, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file/4819114#4819114 if the csv is indeed remote, you still need CORS or a proxy. Presumably if you're on local host you have apache or the like running and you could run your own python/php or what have you to proxy the csv to local. Otherwise it's the same as if your javascript were on a domain name, CORS is required.