# Locally Loading JSON Data into JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm attempting to load a JSON file into my JavaScript file. However, I am at a loss at how to do so.

My **app.js** file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("in here");
    var jsonData = require('../test_data.json'); 

    console.log(jsonData);
}]);
```

I have a **test_data.json** file in my project directory. The error above gives a "require is not defined", so it seems that I must install RequireJS? Is there another way to do so without installing any plugins?

Answer (score 3):

Try using Angular's `$http` service and you'll have more control over the loading, errors, etc:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  console.log("in here");
  $http.get('../test_data.json').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but I got this error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///{file_path_here}. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: You'll need to run it over `http://...` (locally or remotely).  Or disable Chrome's security via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file

Comment: You have to run your app on an app server which supports http calls

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary, what's the fast way to do this? I don't have AngularJS "installed," as I include it in my html file with a script tag pointing to Google CDN.

Comment: there is nothing as a faster way. And you dont need to install AngularJS, your CDN is fine. But when you use `http` protocols, you got to have a Web Server which would handle these calls. You got to install those servers, e.g., Apache Web Server, Apache Tomcat, Nginx etc. You got to install these not AngularJS. Check this, http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/hosting/list_of_web_servers.php3

Comment: try once with @Chris's suggestion about disabling Chrome's security, that should work

And also how does the json file get generated? Where do you fetch it from? You can hardcore those val