# Why cant I execute Javascript on a local HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html script that I embedded in the head of an HTML page that essentially sends page hit counts to a hosted server. When I host this page on Google Drive or any other hosting service, the page works fine and sends usage statics. When I put the file on my local machine and simply open it up on a browser it does not. Why?

FYI, I know this does not work, I am at a loss for the correct explanation.

Answer (score 3):

XHR requests and many other features do not work for pages hosted via the  `file://` protocol. See [Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file).

Answer (score 0):

It won't work in Chrome because of their security model. You can just setup a local server using live reload, browser sync or wamp then it'll work just fine. If u don't wanna mess up so much then I recommend u using **prepros**
It's gives u a simple server with live reload and so many other things. it's free but there's a paid version too. Enjoy!

https://prepros.io/