# Desktop HTML file won't load in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have an .html file saved to my desktop, and when I try to open it in Chrome or Firefox, it stays on the screen that says "Loading..."

If I try to open it in IE, it says "Loading..." but then changes to "Finished Loading" after a few seconds.

I would show the code, but I cannot, as it contains private information, but basically the structure is as follows:

Edit: Will add more information to the structure of the code when I can.

```
<html>
<body>

<div></div>
<div></div>

<script></script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Clear your cache from `chrome/ff`, before. And try it.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide enough code to reproduce the problem, could you please add some more? I understand that it may be private info, but just emit it.

Comment: Can you make an example (free from "private information") that displays this issue?

Comment: @jaunt, I will try to omit as much as possible. Give me a moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is you have an XHR call in the script. Chrome does not load files from the local filesystem via XHR by default. This affects the loading of resources if examples are viewed via the file:// protocol. To enable the loading of such files you should use the new flag --allow-file-access-from-files.

Comment: Does IE allow XHR requests from `file://` URLs?

Comment: Yes, there is an XHR call in the script, that clears up a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Under certain conditions XHR can work under most IE versions, but without seeing the code I have no idea whether the conditions are being met :)