# Appending Script SRC Causes Cross Origin Requests Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost

Essentially I have a site that needs dynamically loaded content - specifically locales. I need multi-lingual support for my site, so the general idea is that I have a query param like ?language=english and english would then get appended to the header so that it grabs the right data to be used in my web page. So like:

```
//script 1

//getLanguage() gets the specified query parameter, like 'english'
$('head').append('<script src=' + getLanguage() + '.js'></script>');
```

Then throughout script 1 I would do like:

```
$('#mainHeader').append(window.i18n['home'].mainHead());
```

And this is the english version of the script where the variables are defined:

```
//english.js

(function(A) {
A.i18n = {
  home: {
    mainHead: function(b) { return 'test123'; },
  }
}
})(this);
```

This works when running on a local webserver. Running it as a file (which is what I need to do) I get this:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://...english.js?_=1449747918242. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." **AND** "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'home' of undefined"

I have attempted to use pure javascript, and this gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'home' of undefined":

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= getLanguage() + '.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I have been trying various potential solutions for a day now and nothing seems to work.

Comment: `file://` ... chrome doesn't like doing stuff like that in `file` protocol

Comment: Ok what you are saying is that you want to run local file from a webpage deserved from external server? Why don't you put your included script on server?

Comment: jQuery has a system for handling strings of HTML. That system is incompatible with adding scripts. It has a workaround for this which uses Ajax. This breaks on cross-origin requests. The pure JavaScript work around you have should solve it, but you need to be a lot more specific than "causes problems".

Comment: I want to run a local file, as a webpage, calling other local files.

Comment: That's it then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file

Comment: @Quentin When I say "causes problems" it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'home' of undefined"

Comment: You have to wait for the script to load and execute before you can use the results from it.

Comment: @A.Wolff that deals with the issues with chrome, this is to be cross-browser, so I want to fix the issues caused by jQuerys security policies

Comment: @Quentin sure but here the script isn't loaded. OP should check the net regarding error he gets

Comment: @A.Wolff — It is loaded when he uses the code in the final script block, it just doesn't run *between* that code running and the stuff marked as "Then throughout script 1"

Comment: @Quentin How can I ensure the script has loaded and executed before the other scripts?

Comment: @WilliamPaul — `load` events maybe.

Comment: @WilliamPaul That's not the way it should be done. Running local server is your best bet. If it's not possible because e.g you share just some file to user and let them to run it inside their own browser without any running local server, i don't see any solution...

Comment: @Quentin Ok so i completly misunderstood it

Comment: @Quentin so I need english.js to load BEFORE my script1 ?

Comment: @WilliamPaul — Before you execute the specific statements in it which depend on the results of english.js. They can be defined in functions and then called later.

Comment: @Quentin essentially every statement in script1 revolves around appending html to divs with data from english.js

Comment: @Quentin so really I need to run this script before everything else

Comment: @Quentin and surely if 
`$('head').append('<script src=' + getLanguage() + '.js'></script>');` works on local host, then my javascript solution should ?

Comment: Do you realize that telling it to load a resource from somewhere other than the source server is the exact *definition* of a cross origin request?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer the resource I am trying to load is in the same place as the html file

Comment: You indicated in your question that you are pointing at it with `file://...`

Comment: @DavidHoelzer not directly, the html file is also under the file:/// domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue related to:

```
$('head').append('<script src=' + getLanguage() + '.js></script>');
```

Fixed by:

```
document.write('<' + 'script src=' + getLanguage() + '.js' + ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
```

jQuery seems to have issues relating to making non-http requests to files on the same domain.