# Angular crashes chrome on a local machine - maybe an ui-router issue?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I am experiencing a strange issue with AngularJS on a local (windows) environment. I use two bootstrap frameworks build with angular ([homer](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/homer-responsive-admin-theme-WB055J451) and [neuboard](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/neuboard-webapp-admin-theme-WB0M35410)). When I run the template (both!) in its AngularJS version locally on windows Chrome freezes completely and causes a huge cpu activity. Firefox on the other hand works fine.

When I upload the same files (distributed template, now compilation neccessary) on my server both chrome and firefox are working fine!

Has anybody experienced something like that or a clue whats causing this?
I have one: Both use angulars ui-router. Maybe Chrome has in this case a problem with resolving/routing the URL, if it starts with file:///C:/...?

Kind regards,
Nico

Comment: When you said Crashed May be you need to update with Console error .. or some related code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by chromes web security itself. By default chrome doesn't allow HTTP-Request from cross origins from other protocols than http, https, data, chrome and so on - but not from file:///

According to this question: [Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)
I started chrome without Web Security and everything workes fine!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to check the dev tools in the browser. Check for errors and also the Network tab (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

You can precisely tell which operation took too long.

I sometimes had issues with cross-referencing on a local machine which is only an issue on some browsers (normally a useful security measure). There is a plugin to turn this off, if that is the error.