# json returned in chrome console but not from code

Tags: jquery, json

I have the code below:

```
var allitems = "<option value=''>Choose an item</option>";
$.getJSON("http://localhost:59886/getItems", function (data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (parseInt(value.C_CODE) == parseInt($("#ccode").val())) { 
      allitems = allitems + "<option value='" + value.itemid+ "'>" + value.itemname + "</option>"; 
    };
  });
}, 'json').error(function (error) { console.log(error); });
```

When I run the code in Chrome console, I get values but when I ran it from a website, the allitems variable is empty. The JSON URL works fine.

Comment: How do you know `allitems` is empty? What is expected vs actual behavior here?

Comment: from this line: if (parseInt(value.C_CODE) == parseInt($("#ccode").val(), I add items to allitems.

Comment: theres no possible way from this code alone for `allitems` to ever be empty.

Comment: I don't see any code adding to `items`; is it `items` that you're seeing as empty?

Comment: it is only returning <option value=''>Choose an item</option>" even if it matches some items in the JSON data returned.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open the page on server. Check your URL and instead of local file, for example:

```
file:///D:/wamp/www/index.html
```

it should start with `http` protocol and `localhost`:

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

Chrome does not allow ajax requests on file url by default, though it [may be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file#answer-18137280).