# angularjs routing is not working in my sample example

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run an angularjs routing example but unable to run.
        The below is the code snippet.
        // Main.html

```
        <body ng-app="myApp">

        <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

        <a href="#london">City 1</a>
        <a href="#paris">City 2</a>

        <p>Click on the links to read about London and Paris.</p>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl : "main.html"
            })
            .when("/london", {
                templateUrl : "london.html"
            })
            .when("/paris", {
                templateUrl : "paris.html"
            });
        });
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

london.html

```
        <h1>London</h1>
        <h3>London is the capital city of England.</h3>
        <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>{{msg}}</p>
```

paris.html

```
    <h1>Paris</h1>
    <h3>Paris is the capital city of France.</h3>
    <p>Th`enter code here`e Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe, with more than 12 million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
```

Please help me to run this example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: yes sujith ji, error like this

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/nageswar_test/paris.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You have three 'when' states, can you also add in an 'otherwise' state, just in case? That might solve some problems you're having.

Comment: templateUrl might not  be finding the given html route check it once

Answer (score 0):

Observing your comments, I believe that this post may solve your problem:

[Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)

By the way, make sure that you are loading the ngRoute script after angularJs script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you obtain Angular routing js and add a reference to it, in your index.html

```
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```