# CSV to HTML not working on chrome

Tags: html, csv

I'm new to csv and am currently trying implement csv external data into my html table and am currently using this guide.
http://www.webslesson.info/2017/04/csv-file-to-html-table-using-ajax-jquery.html 
The code here works in firefox but does not work in chrome. What is the reason for this and how do you fix it?[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnauL.png)

Comment: I have Chrome `Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)` here and it works. Which version of Chrome have you tried? find out in options->Help->About

Comment: Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit) This works on the demo but doesnt work when i throw it into notepad ++

Comment: close the csv file and try again

Comment: I've just tried that but still have the same issue.... It works on firefox but not on chrome

Comment: are you getting errors in console? is JS enabled in your browser?

Comment: JS is enabled I've uploaded the error from the console as an image

Comment: I see, you're getting CORS. For some reason Chrome believes the csv file is in a different domain and block the Ajax call for security reasons. Even if the file is in the same folder, Chrome reports CORS error. Deploying both files to localhost solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)