# "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///... Preflight response is not successful" error

Tags: jquery, safari, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a website and the page loads a navbar and some other resources with Jquery .load() function (as seen in code below).

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#navbar-placeholder").load("subpage_navbar.html");
        });
</script>
```

When viewing the .html files locally on my computer in safari 5 everything works fine, and it used to work fine in safari 11, but now when I try to open the file I get an error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///... Preflight response is not successful

Are there any preferences I need to change in safari for this to work like it used to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest dont work with file protocol only with  http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

you need to host your file or use something like this link bellow to allow this.

[Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)

In Safari 11 file protocol access are limited.

[CORS and cross origin access from file:// are now blocked unless Disable Local File Restrictions is selected from the Develop menu.]

Comment: but I was able to get it to work before with file protocol, and it still works in safari 5. The network log shows the request as a GET method, text/html type, (pending) status.

Comment: "CORS and cross origin access from file:// are now blocked unless Disable Local File Restrictions is selected from the Develop menu."
[See more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Safari_11_0/Safari_11_0.html)

Comment: ok after checking the Disable Local File Restrictions in the develop menu everything works now. Thank you!