# Load json via file URI scheme

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Imagine you only have the chance to load a html file via a file URI scheme:

`file://anypath/index.html`

Inside fhe index.html you load a js file:

```
<script src="./index.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
```

Inside the index.js you need a json file:

```
 ...
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.open('GET', 'index.json', true);
...
```

The Problem is you can not do a XMLHttpRequest via file:// URI scheme (Or?) ... Is there any way to get a external json file which is located at the same folder where the index.html is located?

Comment: *"Is there any way to get a external json file which is located at the same folder where the index.html is located?"* It should work just fine if you load `index.html` via a webserver.

Comment: @FelixKling: Sure but "Imagine you only(!!!) have the chance to load a html file via a file URI scheme". What if you do not have the chance to put a webserver on the device ... ähm ... yes ... and you do not have the chance to connect to another webserver.  "Imagine you only(!!!) have the chance to load a html file via a file URI scheme". No http-Request!

Comment: Depends on the browser you are using then. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4819060/218196. This has nothing to do with JSON or JavaScript itself.

Comment: Why don't you put everything in one file (index.html)?

Comment: I have a index.html, index.js and a index.json. That is the starting position! I use a android tablet and have to call the file://index.html. The index.json is generated by another process. It is not possible to change the starting position!  index.html, index.js and a index.json and no http requests.