# graph editor doesnt open in locally in the browser

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am trying to run graph editor example in mxgraph. But i am unable to run it locally on my system.

It gives the error msg of unable to load the resource.
it says that it is blocked by cors.. i have disable  XMLHTTP support in the browser but still same error. i am using it for development processes so want to run it locally.

i expected to run the graph editor locally on my machine. but getting error of unable to load the resources.
the error msg is as follows:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/projects%20bpmn/mxgraph-master/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/resources/grapheditor.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Try running a local HTTP server in your machine and accessing it through localhost:___/.....

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome you could disable web security which would allows you to do XHR locally ([Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)).

However... I tried that and it didn't work with grapheditor, I imagine it has to do with the responses you get when reading from the filesystem using file:///, I'm guessing you don't get 200 and other responses). Also disabling Chrome security is, well... insecure; so I wouldn't recommend that as a *go to* alternative.

From what I've tried you can go with two alternatives:

- Have your own webserver running somewhere, add grapheditor to some path inside you webserver and access grapheditor that way. There's a disadvantage in running it this way, you don't get all the functionalities because you need some back-end to process stuff and you would have to have one (or create one).
- (I assume you know your way around in a Command Line and that you have java installed) Use the included Java webserver. To run it, download [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi). Then inside the java dir of mxgraph run `ant grapheditor`. The java dir is: mxgraph/java , you will find a build.xml file inside.

I am currently doing some experimentation using the second alternative and it's working ok. I would definitely spend some time on option 2 so you can have grapheditor running smoothly.

Hope this helps...