# What could cause website content to work when hosted online but not when locally downloaded?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib, lime-haxe

I am trying to test some html files locally for my website, it works when using github pages but not when I download my source code to my machine (Chromebook). Could it be haxeflixel, lime or fonts? here is [my repository](https://github.com/Th3SnowyOwl/html-test) if you want to see what I am talking about. I have tried giving local files all permissions in settings. I am wondering what file or source doesn't download to my machine, but works on web pages. (yes I am on internet when testing local files)

Comment: Browsers simply don't allow files to be loaded from the local file system, which is why you need a local webserver for HTML5 game development. `lime` includes one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file might also work.

Comment: [I wouldn't be so sure of that](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Th3SnowyOwl/coding-extras/master/upload.png), but yes, you are right.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean know, like you can't do something like 

`<script type="text/javascript">
  lime.embed ("Funkin", "openfl-content", 1280, 720, { parameters: {} });
</script>`